# Im trying to get the data back from azure database for my xamarin project

Tags: c#, azure

I am very new to all of this. I am trying to create a table service app for my local rugby club. I have connected my app to an Azure sql database, the user can register however when I try to log in nothing happens. This is my class for the user:

```
    using System;
namespace LeighRUFCapp.Model
{
    public class Users
    {
        // [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public string ID { get; set; }

        //  [MaxLength(256)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

bellow is my xaml for the login page;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="LeighRUFCapp.LoginPages.LoginPage" xmlns:yummy="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView">
        <ContentPage.Content>
                <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#313131">
            <Image Source="logo.png" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="40" VerticalOptions="Center"></Image>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="20" AnchorY="0.5" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                <Entry Placeholder="Email" TextColor="White" PlaceholderColor="LightGray" Keyboard="Email" x:Name="EmailAddressEntry"></Entry>
                <Entry Placeholder="Password" TextColor="White" PlaceholderColor="LightGray" IsPassword="True" x:Name="UserPasswordEntry"></Entry>

                   <yummy:PancakeView BackgroundColor="#EFCC45" CornerRadius="20,20,20,20" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="50" Margin="25,0,25,0">
                  <yummy:PancakeView.Shadow>
                    <yummy:DropShadow Color="#232323" Offset="10,10"/>
                </yummy:PancakeView.Shadow>
                 <Button x:Name="LoginButton" Clicked="LoginButton_Clicked" Text="Login" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BorderColor="#000000" BackgroundColor="#EFCC45" FontFamily="helvetica"  TextColor="#000000"></Button>
                 </yummy:PancakeView>

                   <yummy:PancakeView BackgroundColor="#EFCC45" CornerRadius="20,20,20,20" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="50" Margin="25,0,25,0">
                  <yummy:PancakeView.Shadow>
                    <yummy:DropShadow Color="#232323" Offset="10,10"/>
                </yummy:PancakeView.Shadow>
                <Button x:Name="RegisterBtn" Clicked="RegisterBtn_Clicked"  Text="Register" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BorderColor="#000000" BackgroundColor="#EFCC45" FontFamily="helvetica" FontSize="Large" TextColor="#000000"></Button>

                 </yummy:PancakeView>

            </StackLayout>

                    <StackLayout>
                        <Button x:Name="Adminbtn" Clicked="Adminbtn_Clicked" Text="Admin" TextColor="#EFCC45" FontFamily="helvetica" FontSize="Subtitle" BackgroundColor="#313131"/>
                    </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

and my c# for the login page;

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using LeighRUFCapp.Homestuff;
using LeighRUFCapp.Model;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace LeighRUFCapp.LoginPages
{
    public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LoginPage()
        {
            SetValue(NavigationPage.HasNavigationBarProperty, false);

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void LoginButton_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {


            bool isEmailEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailAddressEntry.Text);
            bool isPasswordEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserPasswordEntry.Text);

            if (isEmailEmpty || isPasswordEmpty)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Error", "Your Email or Password is incorrect", "OK");
            }
            else
            {
                var user = await App.MobileService.GetTable<Users>().Where(u => u.Email == EmailAddressEntry.Text).ToListAsync();




                if (user != null)
                {
                    //if (Users.Password == UserPasswordEntry.Text)
                    //{
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
                    /* }

                     else
                     {
                         //password is not being found in the table usersfor some reason
                         await DisplayAlert("Error", "Incorrect email or password", "OK");

                     }

                 }

                 else
                 {
                     await DisplayAlert("Error", "There was an error logging you in", "OK");

                 }*/
                }

            }
        }

        void RegisterBtn_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new RegisterPage());

        }

        void Adminbtn_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new AdminLogin());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice is this:

1. Put the data retrieval behind a service (WebAPI)
2. Call the service from your Mobile application

This is more secure and a common pattern for mobile applications. You will generally design a rest API with JSON as the response type. This will mean spinning up the service in Visual Studio before starting the Xamarin app (assume Android - if not, you end up needing a Mac) by right clicking. Or you can do a separate instance of the service. Once debugged, VS makes it very easy to deploy to the Azure cloud.

Can you access the database remotely? Yes, but you have to turn off some security features or utilize access through HTTPS, or similar. It is not a great pattern, as you end up with connection strings in your application. Not that mobile apps are that easy to reverse engineer to get the information, but following best practices is advised.